# Getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, nosuchelementexception

I have to make a report using three text files. So I thought of storing file data in arrays.This is the text file that I'm using.

```
    UnitID    UName  RNo     RName      Lect   RCapacity    StuEnrolled
    ECSC410;  SDP01; 21;    BreakRoom;  Dr.Fo;   6;             4;
    ECSI707;  SDP02; 23;    BreakRoom;  Dr.Fu;   8;             3;
```

Here's my code. I get the `NoSuchElementException`. I can't figure out why this happens. Please help me to fix it.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getRecords() {
    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<>();

    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\lecturer.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();

        while ( line != null){
            line = br.readLine();
            records.add(line);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lecture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lecture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return records;

}

public static ArrayList<Lecture> getLectureDetails(){
    ArrayList<Lecture> lectureDetails = new ArrayList<>();



    for (String record : getRecords()){
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(record, ";");
        Lecture lecture = new Lecture();

        while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
            lecture.setUnitID(token.nextToken().trim());
            lecture.setUnitName(token.nextToken().trim());
            lecture.setRoomNo(token.nextToken().trim());
            lecture.setRoomName(token.nextToken().trim());
            lecture.setLecturerName(token.nextToken().trim());
            lecture.setRoomCapacity(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken().trim()));
            lecture.setNoOfStudentsEnrolled(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken().trim()));

            lectureDetails.add(lecture);
        }
    }
    return lectureDetails;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Some rows in your text file couldn't has the same number of column!

Comment: first line doest not have all collumn

Comment: Do you have a space-only line in your text file? Probably, the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your while loop for the buffered reader. You're checking the previous value isn't null, rather than checking the next! If line isn't null, it satisfies your condition, but you're then getting the next line and using that. Re-arrange your logic:

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\lecturer.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null){
            records.add(line);
        }
```

**Update:**
If you're doing this to skip the header as a commenter below mentioned quite correctly, then you can still leave in your initial readLine:

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\lecturer.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();

        while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null){
            records.add(line);
        }
```

**As a side note:**

StringTokenizer is a legacy class, and is not recommended for use. Instead, you should make use of the split method on Strings:

```
    for (String record : records) {

        String[] tokens = record.split(";");

        lecture.setUnitID(tokens[0].trim());
        lecture.setUnitName(tokens[1].trim());
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I think he does this to skip the header

Comment: @name_no He may do, but it means he's reading in the line under the content that isn't a line, and thus returns null.

Comment: @name_no Thanks for pointing that out though, I've updated the question to help!

Comment: @MasNotsram Thank you! It works. Even the additional information is really useful as I'm new to Java. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have both error in logic and line break embedded into every line.

First, you tokenize first line of your data with `StringTokenizer`, than you check it have any tokens with `hasMoreTokens()`, then you pull all tokens from it into your `Lecture` object. You think then you get next line, but no.

Then the `while` loop checks again your first data line with `hasMoreTokens` and it still have one last token, the line break symbol. So the loop goes to second run, but this time data have only one token and you get the error.